# Extra detail for images that will be scaled on mobile devices

Tags: android, ios, html, mobile

I have a web game that has images for characters that I let the browser scale because I show them in multiple sizes on different pages, so I just want to cache them once.  So, lets say an image is 500 pixels on a character page, but scaled down to 48 pixels on the map.

I have everything working on mobile browsers great, even drag and drop. But when you pinch zoom, the 48 pixels are scaled up. Since the images have additional resolution, is there any way to get the browser to use the additional resolution? Maybe using some crazy viewport setting?

And if so, will it screw up the positions on drag and drop?